# Print option in tablet and mobile for pdf document

Tags: mobile, coldfusion, tablet

Using coldfusion and mysql.
The application is generating a page in pdf and the desktop users are able to take print by the built in print option of pdf. However, the tablet and mobile users are unable to take the same and need thatprovision for pdf document displayed in tablet and mobile(The default print feature of tab may not be familiar for common users).
What will be the better way to do this programatically?

Thanks

Comment: If you are loading a PDF from the mobile browser, that is the best you can do. In order to print from mobile browser the user must be on a network sharing a printer wireless. Like AirPrint from Apple.

Comment: I misread your question maybe. Desktop users are printing the web page to pdf and you need that for mobile. You'll have to use coldfusion to generate the pdf and send that to the browser. Look at `cfdocument`, `cfdocumentitem`, and `cfcontent`.